# Blade Syntax - Retrieve Item that starts with a number

Tags: string, laravel, escaping, laravel-blade

I've got a small question on which i unfortunately couldn't find the answer for on google.

I am using laravel and I am currently trying to retrieve a column in my Blade View like so:

```
$post->id (this returns the post id)
```

but if the starting string has a number im lost

```
$post->30posts
```

Any idea on how to escape this number in blade?
Thanks in advance,
Regards
Desory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use like this way:

```
$post->{'30posts'}
```